# How to update fragments in viewpager in tablayout with database using only one fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-database

this is Sqlite helper class to retrive data from database

```
public class Simple1 extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "yogalite.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String ID="id";
    private static final String NAME="name";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION="description";


    private static final String POSES_TABLE="poses";

    public Simple1(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public ArrayList<Poses> getPoses(){
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns={Simple1.ID,Simple1.NAME,Simple1.DESCRIPTION};

        Cursor cursor=db.query(Simple1.POSES_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);


        return questionsArrayList;
    }
```

this is my Activity to view tabs and viewpager the tabs should be added dynamically using the number of entries in database

```
public class Learner_2 extends AppCompatActivity {
Context context;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
Simple1 myDatabase;

    ArrayList<Poses> posesArrayList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_learner_2);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs_2);


for(int i = 1 ; i< 5 ; ++i) {


    for (int j = 1; j <5; j++ ){
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_learn));

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_write));

    }
}



        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        final PagerAdapter2 adapter = new PagerAdapter2
                (getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount(),getApplicationContext());












        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {



                  viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }


            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_learner_2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }}
```

this is my fragment

```
public class Learn2 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    TextView Answer;
    TextView Question;
    String Ques, Ans;
    Simple1 myDatabase;
    private ArrayList<Poses> posesArrayList;




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_learner_2, container, false);
        Answer = v.findViewById(R.id.explain);
        Answer.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());


        Question = v.findViewById(R.id.text_title);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null && args.containsKey("categoryName") && args.containsKey("categoryId")) {
            Ques = args.getString("categoryName");
            Ans = args.getString("categoryId");
        }
            Question.setText("" + Ques);
            Answer.setText("" + Ans);

            return v;
        }
    }
```

this is my PagerAdapter

```
 public class PagerAdapter2 extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private int mNumOfTabs;
Simple1 myDatabase;
Context context;

  ArrayList<Poses> posesArrayList;
    public PagerAdapter2(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs ,Context mcontext) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
        this.context= mcontext;
    }





    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {


        myDatabase = new Simple1(context);

        posesArrayList = myDatabase.getPoses();

String Question= posesArrayList.get(position).name;
String Answer= posesArrayList.get(position).description;


Learn2 fsp = new Learn2();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("categoryName", Question);
        args.putString("categoryId", Answer);
        fsp.setArguments(args);

return fsp;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }

}
```

I want to update fragments in view pager in tablayout with database using only one fragment and the number of tabs created should be dynamic depending on database entries.